# Number of ways in which 3 identical red balls and 3 identical white balls can be distributed in between 3 distinct boxes, no box is empty?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

As mentioned in the title, we need to *calculate the number of ways in which 3 identical red balls and 3 identical white balls can be distributed in between 3 distinct boxes such that no box is empty.*

There have been a few similar questions asked, but none which completely answers this particular question (as per my knowledge).

I tried to approach this by making a few cases, which actually ended up working. But I was not able to create a general approach for, say n identical objects of one type and m identical objects of another type in p different boxes.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out myself after reading some of the other answers. Basically we can consider the distribution of each colour separately. After that we just have to use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to arrive at an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start we have $6$ white balls. We can have  $\{4,1,1\}$, $\{3,2,1\}$, or $\{2,2,2\}$ balls in the boxes, with $3$, $6$, $1$ different orderings in the three cases. We now paint three of the six balls red. In the $\{4,1,1\}$ case we can paint three of the $4$ red ($1$ way), two of the $4$ red ($2$ ways), or one of the $4$ red ($1$ way); makes $4$ ways. In the $\{3,2,1\}$ case we can paint all three of the $3$ red ($1$ way), two of the three red ($2$ ways), one of the $3$ red ($2$ ways), or none of the $3$ red ($1$ way); makes $6$ ways. In the $\{2,2,2\}$ case we can make $2$ and $1$ red balls in different boxes ($6$ ways) or one red ball in each box ($1$ way); makes $7$ ways.

In all, there are
$$3\cdot 4+6\cdot 6+1\cdot 7=55$$
different admissible distributions.

Answer (score 1):

**Case A.** 4 balls in the first box.

1. In the box we can find 3 red balls & 1 white or 3 white balls & 1 red. This means exactly one arranjament for second and third box. *Subtotal:2 permutations*
2. In the box we can find 2 red balls & 2 white balls. This means two possivle arranjaments for second and third box. *Subtotal:2 permutations*
   **Total:4 permutations**

**Case B.** 3 balls in the first box.

1. 3 red or 3 white. This means 2 arranjaments in the other boxes. *Subtotal:4 permutations*
2. 2 red + 1 white or 1 red + 2 white. This means 4 possible arranjaments in the other boxes. *Subtotal:8 permutations*
   **Total:12 permutations**

**Case C.** 2 balls in the first box.

1. 2 red or 2 white. This means 6 possible arranjaments in the other boxes. *Subtotal:12 permutations*
2. 1 red & 1 white. This means 7 possible arranjaments in the other boxes. *Subtotal:7 permutations*
   **Total:19 permutations**

**Case D.** 1 ball in the first box.
Only one way: 1 red or 1 white. This means 10 possible arranjaments in the other boxes.
**Total:20 permutations**

Conclusion: `4 + 12 + 19 + 20 = 55` possible permutations.

Comment: Case C, part 2: rw-rrw-w, rw-rww-r, rw-rr-ww, rw-rw-rw, rw-ww-rr, rw-r-rww, rw-w-rrw makes seven, not three. Also, I get $20$, not $16$, in Case D. Total: $55$.

Comment: Spelling: arrangements.